# Method throws null reference exception after returning non-null value

Tags: c#, entity-framework, automapper, nullreferenceexception, dto

I have a service method that very simply gets the information for all stores in the database. It maps the stores from EF using Auto Mapper, and returns a generic response of type StoreDTO (a simple POCO).

The problem is this: the method executes just fine, I step through all the way to the end. Every property in `response` has a value, nothing is null. The list is populated with items, the items in the list are valid, etc etc.

But the following code throws a NullReferenceException as soon as `GetAllStores` returns:

```
ListResponseDTO<StoreDTO> allStores = Services.Stores.Stores.GetAllStores();
```

EDIT: Here is a screenshot of the debugger, right when it is returning. You can see in the watch window that the values look kosher: https://i.stack.imgur.com/NhDsU.png

Any help is greatly appreciated. Here is the code from the method:

```
    public static ListResponseDTO<StoreDTO> GetAllStores()
    {
        ListResponseDTO<StoreDTO> response = new ListResponseDTO<StoreDTO>("Get Stores not successful");

        try
        {
            response.Items = new List<StoreDTO>();
            using (DomainEntities db = new DomainEntities(Global.ConnectionString))
            {
                foreach (var IndividualStore in db.Stores)
                {
                    Mapper.CreateMap<Store, StoreDTO>();
                    var IndividualStoreDTO = Mapper.Map<Store, StoreDTO>(IndividualStore);
                    response.Items.Add(IndividualStoreDTO);
                }
            }
            response.Message = "Store(s) retrieved successfully";
            response.Success = true;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Logging.Log("Get All Stores", response.Message + " " + ex.ToString(), Logging.LogPriority.Error, "Store Operations");
        }
        return response;
    }
```

Here is the generic DTO definition:

```
public class ListResponseDTO<DtoType> : ResponseDTO
{
    public ListResponseDTO()
        : base()
    {
        Items = new List<DtoType>();
    }

    public ListResponseDTO(string defaultMessage)
        : base(defaultMessage)
    {
        Items = new List<DtoType>();
    }

    public List<DtoType> Items;
}
```

In case you were wondering, `ResponseDTO` has two properties:

`bool Success`

`string Message`

Here is the exception details, I'm afraid it's not too helpful:

```
System.NullReferenceException was unhandled by user code
  Message=Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
  Source=Infinity
  StackTrace:
   at PLM.Infinity.Default.GetDrawersForUser() in C:\Users\jlucas\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\PLM Source Control\Utilities\InfinityInterface\Infinity\Default.aspx.cs:line 96
  InnerException:
```

Comment: Try removing the try/catch and see what happens

Comment: Same thing. It doesn't throw an exception in the method, it only throws it after the method returns.

Comment: What does the GetAllStores Method look like the only way that you are getting Null after returning is because you are either newing it up again or you have some odd recursive method / property call that resets the object also why is this line needed  ListResponseDTO<StoreDTO> response = new ListResponseDTO<StoreDTO>("Get Stores not successful");

Comment: @DJKRAZE: The `GetAllStores` method is the second snippet of code.

Comment: The generic ListResponseDTO takes a string in the constructor to set the return message. If an exception is thrown, the original response is returned with the message "not successful," and the boolean value `success` remains false. if the method executes successfully the message is changed to one of success.

Comment: @DJKRAZE: It doesn't appear to be overloaded, and `response.Items` is a `List<StoreDTO>` (see snippet 3) so no problem there.

Comment: @DJKRAZE: Doesn't really matter. `List<StoreDTO>` ≠ `ListResponseDTO<DtoType>`.

Comment: Well even looking at the code it should not return null when it gets to the line return response; so there must be somewhere else in code where this response is being nulled out... just noticed something where is allstores being used..???

Comment: Can you post the complete stack trace of the exception?

Comment: @DJKRAZE Exactly. It should not be returning null, yet after the method returns it throws the exception. I stepped through every line of code, down to the brackets surrounding the method, and `response` was not null. But the program thinks it is.

Comment: What are the types of `Services.Stores` and `Services.Stores.Stores`? There could be a huge, hidden deferred-execution problem.

Comment: @minitech `Services.Stores` is a namespace, and `Services.Stores.Stores` is a static service class with no properties, only methods.

Comment: Your stack trace seems to verify that suspicion, too. I don't know about databases in .NET, but that looks like the problem.

Comment: Can you show more context to where you are calling `Services.Stores.Stores.GetAllStores()`? and did the stack trace have anything in the inner exception or is that actually where it stopped?

Comment: The stack trace I posted is complete, I used "copy exception information to clipboard," and `InnerException` was null. I also posted a screenshot of the debugger: http://i.imgur.com/rd853.png

Comment: Presumably `GetDrawersForUser()` is the method with the line `ListResponseDTO<StoreDTO> allStores = Services.Stores.Stores.GetAllStores();` in it? Also I presume that from your screenshot its when you click step over at that point and it returns to the parent that this is when it immediately throws the error? Is there any chance of seeing more of the `GetDrawersForUser()` method to get an idea if its anything to do with how you are calling it?

Comment: Without seeing the calling code I don't think anyone can help you.  Specifically we need the code surrounding line 96 of Default.aspx.cs file; and, if that's a method call to yet something else, that code.

Answer (score 0):

Can you put a where clause so you return only stores that you are sure they have all fields, and see if the problem persists?

This some times happen because, somewhere in your data set, you have missing data and during debug you don't see it.

You could also put another try catch that boxes the Mapper call and see if something is happening there.

This are more suggestions then an answer.